# Behavior of default model binder with custom object while model binding

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

In the below code my 'tc' object has been initialized after posting, but values are null. What is the root cause of the issue. Why is the default model binder doesn't attempt to populate the properties with incoming posted values? What restriction the default model binder has to behave like this?

```
  <form id="hello-world" action="/Home/Index">
        <label for="user">User  </label>
        <input id="user" type="text" name="user" required="required">
        <label for="city"> City </label>
        <input id="city" type="text" name="city" required="required">
        <label for="age"> Age </label>
        <input id="age" type="text" name="age" required="required">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>


 public ActionResult Index(TestClass tc)
   { 
     ViewBag.TCName = tc.user; // its null
     ViewBag.TCAge = tc.age; // its null
     ViewBag.TCCity = tc.city; // its null
     return View();
    }
public class TestClass
{
    public string user;
    public string city;
    public string age;
}
```

Comment: Please post the code of your `TestClass`! Because what you've shown should work if your use properties and not fields! on your `TestClass`...

Comment: @nemesv , done. posted

Comment: I made it as a property and it works fine. But why isn't working with fields?

Comment: Because the model binder works only with properties and it ignores fields. If you are writing OOP code in .NET, you should consider using properties for better encapsulation anyways. when I see a public field on a class, it's usually a sign of bad design.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [`properties`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9fsa0sw.aspx) and not [`fields`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173118.aspx) on your view model:

```
public class TestClass
{
    public string User { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string Age { get; set; }
}
```

The default model binder can only bind to properties with public getters/setters and not with fields. It simply ignores fields and they will never be initialized.

Comment: can u come to chat pls